# How to stop "abrtd" permanently?

Tags: abrt

How to stop `abrtd` permanently?

It is filling up the log space and I don't need abrtd logs.

1. Is this command sufficient?

   ```
   $ systemctl stop abrtd
   ```
2. Will `abrtd` be back up and running with system re-start?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`stop` stops the current invocation. You will also need to disable it to prevent it from starting up again:

```
systemctl disable abrtd
```